# .mp3 files size is 0 after upload in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

In Laravel 9, When I upload an mp3 file, there is no problem on my local environment which is windows and XAMPP. But on the server which is Linux Ubuntu and my webserver is Apache when the file is uploaded, its size equals 0.

In addition, other file types such as images and even different audio file types do not have problems and they work correctly.

Also, I've added mime types support in the `.htaccess` file but it hasn't solved the problem.
For clearing up my question I'll add my codes below.

`.htaccess` in `pulic` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Video support
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogv .ogv

# Audio support
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/oga .oga
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/wav .wav

# For HLS support
AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8
AddType vnd.apple.mpegURL .m3u8
AddType video/MP2T .ts

# For M(PEG)-DASH support
AddType application/dash+xml .mpd

# For subtitles support
AddType text/vtt .vtt
AddType text/srt .srt
```

***Update 1:***

`UploadController`:

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(private Uploader $uploader)
    {

    }

    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
      return $this->uploader->upload();
    }


}
```

`Uploader`:

```
class Uploader
{
private $file;

public function __construct(private Request $request)
{
    $this->file = $this->request->file;
}

public function upload()
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $folderName = $this->getFolderName();

        $this->saveFileIntoDatabase($folderName);

        $this->putFileIntoStorage($folderName);

        DB::commit();

        return $folderName;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return '';

    }
}

private function saveFileIntoDatabase(string $folderName)
{
    return TemporaryFile::create([
        'folder' => $folderName,
        'file_name' => $this->getFileName()
    ]);
}

private function getFolderName()
{
    return uniqid() . '-' . now()->timestamp;
}

private function getFileName()
{
    return $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
}

private function putFileIntoStorage(string $folderName)
{
    return $this->file->storeAs(config('filesystems.temporary_file_path') . $folderName,$this->getFileName());
}

}
```

and in `filesystems.php`, `temporary_file_path` is:

```
    'temporary_file_path' => 'tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```

Comment: Add the part of code where you're handling the upload. This has nothing to do with the htaccess conf

Comment: @OMiShah I added the codes related to uploading, you can see them now, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Is it necessary to write tons of codes for a simple file uploading?

Comment: @EHFShahab I just wanted to keep my controller clean and send upload responsibility to another class, also in the Uploader class, I just tried to obey the single responsibility rule.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encountered this problem:

In my case, This problem appeared due to the upload max file size in `php.ini`.

To solve that you should change it. The three files you have there are each meant for different uses.

`/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini` is for the CLI PHP program, which you found by running `php` on the terminal.

`/etc/php/5.6/cgi/php.ini` is for the php-cgi system which isn't specifically used in this setup.

`/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini` is for the PHP plugin used by Apache. This is the one you need to edit for changes to be applied for your Apache setup which utilizes the in-built PHP module to Apache.

`/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini` is for the `php5-fpm` processor, which is a fastcgi-compatible 'wrapper' for PHP processing (such as to hand off from NGINX to php5-fpm) and runs as a standalone process on the system (unlike the Apache PHP plugin)

For versions of Ubuntu lower than 16.04, `/etc/php/5.6/`,`/etc/php/7.0/`,`/etc/php/7.1/`, and so on, are replaced by `/etc/php5/` and so on. Otherwise, these paths remain accurate. Adapt this accordingly for your environment, replacing the `5.6` or number with the actual version folder that exists in your environment.

open `php.ini` then, find `upload_max_filesize`, after that change the value as much as you need, for instance `8M`. After that, save the file.

Eventually, do not forget to restart the Apache.

In `Ubuntu` you could do it by this command:

`sudo service apache2 restart`